# Get dimensions of JPEG in C++

Tags: c++, jpeg, openvms

I need to get the image dimensions of a JPEG in C++. I'm looking for either a fairly simple way to do it or a smallish library that provides that functionality. I'm working in C++ on OpenVMS, so any external libraries may have to be adapted to compile on our systems - so please don't post me links to big, closed source libraries!

Has anyone come across anything that might do the trick, or understand the JPEG file format (I think I probably mean the JFIF file format here) to tell me how I might go about rolling my own solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have this [C function](http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/stuff/jpegsize.html) which may extract the relevant data for you.

> This is a C routine but should compile fine with C++.
>   Pass it a normal FILE pointer (from fopen) to the beginning of a jpeg file and two int pointers to be set with the image height and width.

Or you may find in the [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io.hpp) a jpeg class which has the right function (From [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/technology/graphics/generic_image_library.html) [Generic Image Library](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/gil/Generic+Image+Library)).

[jpeg_read_dimensions](http://stlab.adobe.com/gil/html/group___j_p_e_g___i_o.html#ga4)

```
boost::gil::jpeg_read_dimensions (const char *filename)
```

> Returns the width and height of the JPEG file at the specified location. Throws std::ios_base::failure if the location does not correspond to a valid JPEG file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - just disappeared off to get married! Back at my desk now :-(.

I opted for the C routine (though the #defines at the top are HORRIBLE - rewrote those as functions).

Comment: Congratulation to both of you!

Comment: return Many Happy
return Many Happy!

Comment: @VonC first link is dead, but here's another, looks the same? http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/stuff/jpegsize.html

Comment: @Steve Thank you. The first link is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

libjpeg is reasonably small, open source and available on OpenVMS. It's probably quicker to install it than to handle JPEG yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [libjpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this [jpeg lib](http://ftp://ftp.uu.net/graphics/jpeg/) with this [patch for OpenVMS](http://nchrem.tnw.tudelft.nl/openvms/software2.html#Jpeglib)

Answer (score 1):

No need for full libjpeg library just to get this information (unless you need to do something else with the images). [ImageInfo](http://schmidt.devlib.org/image-info/index.html) might help you. It is a Java class, but there are ports for other languages, including C++.
As pointed out, Exif might change these information (eg. with orientation setting).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [GDAL](https://gdal.org/) library which serves as an abstraction layer for large number of raster data formats, mostly used in geospatial applications for GIS/RS.

GDAL provides number of APIs, for C, C++ and scripting languages. Of course, it supports [JPEG](https://gdal.org/frmt_jpeg.html) images and its variants like [JPEG2000](https://web.archive.org/web/20210302193335/https://gdal.org/frmt_jpeg2000.html) and more.

Here is a very simple example how to open JPEG image and query its dimensions:

```
#include <gdal_priv.h>

GDALAllRegister(); // call ones in your application

GDALDataset* ds = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen("my.jpeg", GA_ReadOnly);
int width  = ds->GetRasterXSize();
int height = ds->GetRasterYSize(),
int nbands = ds->GetRasterCount();
```

Check [GDAL API tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html) for more complete example.